# Can I install a wallet on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: wallet, server

I was wondering if I could I install a wallet on Windows Server 2008? If so which wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install "[Bitcoin-Core](https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.11.0/)" (including Bitcoin-Qt) on a window server 2008. It requires initial syncing and verification of around 40GB of data. So it might take 1-2 days until you can use it.

Other option would be to install a SPV client like "[Electrum](https://electrum.org/#home)" (Python based) or "[Multibit HD](https://multibit.org)" (Java / bitcoinj based). They can be used immediately but they won't give you the same level of privacy.

Comment: Thanks, I had to look up what a SPV client was, found it here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client

Comment: Ok, thanks I successfully installed Multi-bit HD on the sever and synced the wallet to a cloud service.