# How can I tell if my Bitcoin wallet is working?

Tags: breadwallet

I'm not sure if my Bitcoin wallet is working, is there a way to check that it's ready to go? I'm using Breadwallet for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

breadwallet is a standalone bitcoin client for mobile devices. There is no server which can get hacked or go offline, so you can always access the funds stored on your phone.

Using [SPV mode](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4649/6441), breadwallet connects directly to the bitcoin network with the fast performance you need on a mobile device.

Since the wallet itself has no indicator for connections and does not synchronize the blockchain, I would suggest that you use a very tiny amount of Bitcoin and send it in a micro transaction to your breadwallet to test if you are set up and connected.

By the way, did you backup your wallet yet?

Comment: I want to use something safe and reliable, should I use greenaddress or just download Bitcoin core on my PC.

Comment: Also yes I have a backup of the recovery code and have scanned the blockchain multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If there is lack of indicators in the software and lack of documentation you can always send some small amounts of bitcoins to your public key from another key.

Answer (score -2):

If it's connected and synced, you're ready to go.

Comment: I think the question is how he can check whether it is connected and synced. Can you tell?