# My Bitcoin Qt is behind 7 years and 32 weeks

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization, bitcoin-qt-setup

My Bitcoin Qt is behind 7 years and 32 weeks... I'm new to all this so I wonder:

- if I shut down the pc, is the sync gonna continue or will it restart from the beginning?
- And.. how can I get my transaction without waiting for 7 years?
- and also, does the sync need bigger [ssd storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)?

Answer (score 7):

If you shut down your PC and then restart, the Bitcoin sync will pick up where it left off.

The latest transaction your Bitcoin currently knows about is 7 years old, but it won't take 7 years to catch up. It should be all caught up in a matter of days.

You will need a lot of storage for Bitcoin Qt. The [current size of the blockchain](https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size) is over 80 GB, and grows at about 4 GB per month. The blockchain is always growing so you will continue to need more space indefinitely.

If you want to use Bitcoin but don't want to store the entire blockchain forever, consider using an SPV client. See the question [What is an SPV client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client) for more information.

Comment: many thanks greg, if it really need bigger storage then can i just import my backup wallet from bitcoin core to another wallet .. btw .. i still behind 5 yrs and 8 weeks to sync.  and i really need to use some BTC from my core wallet . so.. is there any easy way to export my wallet.dat so that i can use some of my BTC to pay my debt as soon as possible.