# Which Bitcoin thin client that can execute on restricted IoT devices?

Tags: thin-clients

I am trying to find a suitable Bitcoin thin client for IoT devices with Linux OSs. IoT devices will act as peers as thin clients, and the selection criteria for the thin client is least CPU, memory and storage requirements. Which Bitcoin thin client protocol would be the best choice for such system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a SVP  Client/wallet like discussed here : [What is an SPV client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client)

IOT is a wide space, you could specify the technical features of your IOT to get the right help, a raspberry pi for example could be considered as an IOT and it could host a full or a light node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main point is I want to find lightest protocol implementation, then I will choose IoT devices according to that. I am trying to figure out lowest device requirements to be part of Bitcoin network, by using one of the thin client protocol, which obviouslyis using SPV.  Do you have any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: I suggest you to explore bitcoinJ they support SPV, you could write your own program and then test it on the Iots to check which requirements you'll need.