# Maysspayout, SendMany, Bulk Payouts with Bitcoin Core

Tags: transactions

Do I have to download the whole bitcoin blockchain (145GB) to be able to do a sendMany transaction with [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download)?

Are there other Desktop Software, where I can do a masspayout?

Maybe an App, where I can read a CSV like this:

address amount,

address amount,

...

Answer (score 1):

Electrum is an [SPV wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client) which means you don't need to download the entire blockchain. It will be up and running in a few minutes

It has a handy [sendtomany](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-do-bulk-payments-with-electrum) feature where you can even upload a csv file