# How to recover my Copay wallet using the 12 word seed phrase

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitpay, copay

I'm new to Bitcoin/Copay. I decided to signup at coinbase deposited $80. I read you needed a wallet. I decided on copay. Transferred the funds to my wallet. Everything processed smoothly and my copay wallet showed $76. I then went to the merchant and tried to pay. A spend password popped up. i couldn't remember the password. I may have mixed it up with my coinbase password instead.

I then did a little digging online and read that I could delete copay from my Android phone and reinstall it using the 12 word phrase to by pass/reset spending password. I did that. Now if I restore using only the phrase it creates a "Personal Wallet" with no funds in it.

If I try and restore wallet with 12 word phrase and try and guess the recovery phrase password (Under Advanced Options) I get an error saying
"Could not access the wallet at the server
Please Check
The password of the recovery phrase (if Set)
The derivation path
The wallet service URL
Is there any way I can recover my wallet/funds I do know the 12 word phrase. and I thought that would have all I would have needed.

Thanks for any help fixing this.

Comment: what is your wallet address for both?

Comment: Copay wallet Address is/was  1DcuwtWQ66FV39AJNcY6SpvbiMoVqWdoer

Comment: the good news you didn't lose your funds, they're still in your wallet/address

Comment: Well they are there but I consider it lost because I can't seem to recover them.

Comment: You may find https://metasafe.org useful

Comment: Could you figure out. I have the same issue. I have the 12 word, but can not recover / import.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Import option when you try to recover the wallet?

This issue looks similar to what you're experiencing: https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/7399

Comment: I have tried create, import, recovery etc.In Copay, Bitpay and Electrum

Answer (score 0):

According to several [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) websites your address 1DcuwtWQ66FV39AJNcY6SpvbiMoVqWdoer still contains 0.00621076 BTC worth today about $40 or half what you bought it for.

There was a single transaction:

```
Date              25-Jan-2018, 01:14:33     
Transaction ID    b5e7252c40a92447960b64d336b05dc1a7334fe06371eeb6eabacaec5ce1 0a00
Confirmations     30888     
Inputs #          1
Outputs #         2
Amount            +0.00621076 btc     
Fees              0.00052679 btc
Fees per byte     233.09 Satoshi
Size (kB)         0.226
```

That transaction would be a transfer from Coinbase to your wallet.

So if you **import** your twelve word recovery-phrase (seed phrase) into a new wallet, you should be able to see an address "1DcuwtWQ66FV39AJNcY6SpvbiMoVqWdoer" in it.

If so, after the wallet has synchronised with the bitcoin network you will see the correct balance. A new full-node wallet may take weeks to synchronise. A web wallet or [SPV wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client) will be quicker (but web wallets are arguably less secure).

Answer (score -1):

I think coinbase cannot not recover it for you but you can ask them.

The paraphrase you copied might be incorrect.

As long as you save all the required informations then there should be a way to recover it.

Comment: I can't see how the 12 word seed is wrong.  When setting up copay for the first time on my Android phone, I typed the words in note pad immediately. The next step in the set up process asks me to select the 12 words in the order it was giving. I selected the 12 words in order by what was I typed in notepad, and completed the setup. I checked each word for spelling by comparing them to the word list. Each is spelled correctly and one space between them.

Comment: hmm... when i used the vault, i remember ill give u a private key which u can use instead of the passphrase but it might updated so my answer may be inaccurate because i havnt use coinbase vault for long time

Comment: I used coinbase to send the funds to my copay wallet. The copay wallet is the one I'm trying to recover. I only used coinbase to buy the bitcoins and then sent it to my copay wallet.

Comment: You contacted them?

Comment: No I haven't. I assumed by what I have read that once it leave and goes to my copay wallet that there would be no way for them to reverse it.

Comment: I will contact them and see if they can.

Comment: If they can't then maybe u will loose the coins.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use the passphrase with their digits and dashes! // 1- banana 2- sugar// ! 
And also there is a second password may be used before,  while setting the strog security of your wallet,  please see that!